# How do I improve loading thousands of tiny JSON files into a Spark dataframe?

Tags: json, apache-spark

I have about 30,000 very tiny JSON files that I am attempting to load into a Spark dataframe (from a mounted S3 bucket). It is reported [here](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/480/how-do-i-ingest-a-large-number-of-files-from-s3-my.html) and [here](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Strategies-for-reading-large-numbers-of-files-td15644.html) that there may be performance issues and is described as the `Hadoop Small Files Problem`. Unlike what has been previously reported, I am not recursing into directories (as all my JSON files are in one sub-folder). My code to load the JSON files look like the following.

```
val df = spark
  .read
  .option("multiline", "true")
  .json("/mnt/mybucket/myfolder/*.json")
  .cache
```

So far, my job seems "stuck". I see 2 stages.

- Job 0, Stage 0: Listing leaf files and directories
- Job 1, Stage 1: val df = spark .read .option("multiline", "...

`Job 0, Stage 0` is quite fast, less than 1 minute. `Job 1, Stage 1`, however, takes forever to even show up (lost track of time, but between the two, we are talking 20+ minutes), and when it does show up on the jobs UI, it seems to be "stuck" (I am still waiting on any progress to be reported after 15+ minutes). Interestingly, `Job 0, Stage 0` has 200 tasks (I see 7 executors being used), and `Job 1, Stage 1` has only 1 task (seems like only 1 node/executor is being used! what a waste!).

Is there any way to make this seemingly simple step of loading 30,000 files faster or more performant?

Something that I thought about was to simply "merge" these files into large ones; for example, merge 1,000 JSON files into 30 bigger ones (using [NDJSON](http://ndjson.org/)). However, I am skeptical of this approach since merging the files (let's say using Python) might itself take a long time (something like the native linux `ls` command in this directory takes an awful long time to return); also, this approach might defeat the purpose of cluster computing end-to-end (not very elegant).

Answer (score 3):

Merging JSON files into newline delimited, much larger (aim for one or at most 10 files, not 30) files would be the only option here.

Python opening 30K files isn't going to be any slower than what you're already doing, it just won't be distributed.

Besides that, `multiline=true` was particularly only added for the cases where you already have a really large JSON file and it's one top level array or object that's being stored. Before that option existed, "JSONLines" is the only format Spark could read.

The most consistent solution here would be to fix the ingestion pipeline that's writing all these files such that you can accumulate records ahead of time, then dump larger batches. Or just use Kafka rather than reading data from S3 (or any similar filesystem)

Comment: I don't have control over the creation of the JSON files.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. Requesting a bunch of files at once from S3 in general means one round trip HTTP request for every file. As you can imagine, that's the bottleneck here, not Spark, and all other tools will have the same problem

Comment: Your feedback is making me think that Spark or Hadoop-esque systems may suffer without data locality. I have 30,000 wave (audio) files corresponding to those JSON files and I was thinking of using Spark for audio processing as well. Fundamentally, I suppose the same issues will manifest as well? With JSON at least there's NDJSON, but what about binary/wav files? Any tips on that? The wave files are 5-10 MB each.

Comment: I guess I can create my own Parquet file locally and upload that to S3.

Comment: I don't know how Audio files make sense in a columnar format with specific types, but I would suggest Bzip2 format archives

Comment: Just to close the loop on condensing many files into a few or just one file. There's a 2 GB limit in Spark for blocks, so that would/will constrain my file size as well, right? Each file used as input to spark must NOT be larger than 2 GB. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1476

Comment: Blocks are different from files. I can confidently say we have a few 6GB Avro files that are in S3 and Spark reads them, according to our data science team

Answer (score 1):

There's two HTTP requests a read, one HEAD, one GET; if the files are all kept in the same dir then the listing cost is simply one LIST/5000 objects, so 6 list calls. You'll pay ~$25 for 30K HEAD & GET calls.

If you are using spark to take the listing and generate a record from each individual file, as well as the overhead of scheduling a task per file. You can do a trick where you make the listing itself (which you do in .py) which becomes the input RDD (i.e one row-per-file) and the map() becomes the read of that file and the output of the map the record representing the single file. [scala example](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/cloud-integration/blob/master/spark-cloud-integration/src/main/scala/com/hortonworks/spark/cloud/applications/CloudCp.scala#L123). This addresses the spark scheduling overhead as that input listing will be split into bigger parts pushed out to the workers, so leaving only those HTTP HEAD/GET calls.

For this to work efficiently, use Hadoop 2.8+ Jars, and do the listing using `FileSystem.listFiles(Path, true)` to a single recursive listing of the entire directory tree under the path, so using the S3 LIST API at its most optimal.

(Once you've done this, why not post the code up somewhere for others?)